# Grant a permission to select the function but not execute in any PL/SQL block

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I know there are only two permissions on procedures/functions - **EXECUTE** and **DEBUG**.
But I want to grant the **EXECUTE** permission to a user in such a way that the user can **select the function using dual** or any other query but **not execute**( to prevent the user from firing DMLs - Insert, update etc) inside any BEGIN-END block.

I know that we can revoke access to tables etc. But that access **has** to be given. The user should be able to do perform **DML** operation, but just not through a function.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: If the user can't change the function then I don't see how they can add any DML to it. If the function currently executes DML, then remove it...

Comment: Actually I got my Answer. Turns out Functions can fire DML from select also.

Comment: No, they can't. You can't use a function that does DML in a select statement; though a function can perform DML if not called from a select statement... I'm really not sure what this question is about.

Comment: @Ben - A function in a select statement can perform a DML from autonomous transaction.

Comment: Thumbs up @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: What do you try to achieve? A procedure can never be called by ´select proc from dual`

Comment: But a function can be. And as @EgorSkriptunoff said, It can fire DMLs from both select and (PL/SQL)block. I thought it wasnt possible to do DML while just selecting. That is why I wanted to grant a specific permission to user to be just able to select the function. But now thats out of the question. :)

Comment: It is you to define if the function contains any DML not rhe caller. Again, what is your goal?

Comment: The functions are already defined in the Database. Some contains DML, some don't.